# Is boilerpipe available in golang?

Tags: html, web, go, machine-learning

Is there any [boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) like project implemented in go language?

i tried searching in google but didn't find any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at Goose:
https://github.com/advancedlogic/GoOse

Answer (score 1):

You have the beginning of that idea is [`mikkolehtisalo/revel/deXSS`](https://github.com/mikkolehtisalo/revel/tree/master/deXSS)

#### `deXSS` - HTML Stripping for Revel

> Options for sanitizing HTML input:
>
> - Escaping everything, e.g. with html.EscapeString
> - Parse HTML input, and filter the nodes using pre-defined rules
>
> This library does the latter for both tags and attributes.

It is not near as complete as boilerpipe, but it is a start.

```
func blahblah() {
    out := FilterHTML("<p>Hello <a mushroom=\"big\" href=\"/snake\">badger</a>!</p><p>Got it?</p>", allowed, true)
    // The attribute "mushroom" was not in allowed, so it will be gone!
    revel.INFO.Printf("Result of filtering: %+v", out)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I could use this in my project